# Подскажите, как удалить только те файлы, в которых 11-я строка пустая?

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль, bat, terminal

Существует .cmd файл:

```
chcp 1251
set vDate=%date:~-10%
set vTime=%time:~0,-3%
set vTime=%vTime::=.%
set vTime=%vTime: =0%
md D:\%vDate%
openfiles /query /s 192.168.1.4 /fo csv /v > D:\%vDate%\%vTime%.txt
```

Который запускается из планировщика и создает папку (к примеру): "D:\14.09.2018" и файлы (к примеру): "09.50.00.txt", "09.55.00.txt", "10.00.00.txt", "10.05.00.txt", "10.10.00.txt"...

Содержимое файла:

```
Информация: Флаг "построение списка объектов" должен
      быть включенным, чтобы видеть открытые локально файлы.
      Подробнее смотрите Openfiles /?.


Файлов, открытых с общих сетевых ресурсов:
---------------------------------------------
"Имя узла","ID","Пользователь","Тип","#Locks","Режим открытия","Открыть файл (<Путь>\<исполнимый файл>)"
"PC","1","АДМИНИСТРАТОР","Windows","0","Чтение и запись","\PIPE\srvsvc"
```

Подскажите, как удалить только те файлы, в которых 11-я строка пустая?

Comment: Проверить содержимое 11-й строки. Если пусто - удалить файл.

Comment: Частично я понимаю что нужно:
FOR /F - цикл;
tokens=11 - смотрим 11-ю строку;
D:\ - ищим на диске "D:\";
%vDate% - в этой папке;
%vTime% - имя файла;
.txt - расширение файла;
rd - удаление;
IF - условие...

А в картину собрать пазлы не получается.

Comment: Буду писать по частям, начну с подсчёта строк: find /v /c "" D:\14.09.2018\09.50.00.txt осталось удалить файлы у которых 11-ть строк.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, из-за неверной постановки задачи, Вы страдаете лишними телодвижениями.
Сформулирую за Вас задачу. При получении лог-перечней открытых файлов с разных серверов, нужно удалить те логи, в которых нет сведений об открытых файлах. В таких логах 11 строка не существует! Значит нужно пролистать все текстовые файлы в каталоге, и удалить только те, в которых поиск 11-ой строки ничего не выдаст.
Получается следующий код:

```
@for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ('dir/b *.txt') do @call :find11 %%~fa

@goto end

:find11
@set a=""
@for /F "tokens=1*" %%x in ('@findstr /n /r ".*" %1 ^|@findstr /b /c:"11:"') do @set a=11
@if %a% equ "" @del/q "%1"

:end
```

Comment: Пример приведен для вызова батника из того же каталога, где лежат текстовые  файлы: *.txt

Comment: У меня пустые строки 1, 5, 6 и 11... В строках: 1, 5, 6 есть - CR LF и если их отслеживать то скрипт работает, а на 11-ю строку скрипт не реагирует.

Comment: **1.** Не понятно, откуда в консольном выводе Window-утилиты могут появится не "виндовые" переводы строк - прошу привести пример выходного файла. **2.** Не ясна постановка задачи: с какой целью нужен листинг открытых файлов?

Comment: Все строки кроме 11-й заканчиваются на CR LF. Да с постановкой - беда, странный подход, создать, а потом удалить, не лучше ли не создавать если больше 11-ти строк.

Comment: На вопрос: "может лучше **НЕ СОЗДАВАТЬ** такие файлы". Я могу ответить, что тогда нужно парсить каждую команду **openfiles /query** и при поступлении пустой строки файлов **НЕ начинать** вывод в файл. Сработает это, если вам в лог-файле не нужны строки информационного заголовка _"Информация: Флаг "п..."_ Хотя и это решаемо...

Comment: Да, так ещё лучше.

Comment: Похоже миссия не выполнима - пришлось поставить Algorius Net Watcher.